# 'Line Break' or 'Shift+Enter' issue (when multiple keyboard layouts are enabled)

Tags: keyboard, ibus

### Issue Behaviour:

Can not add a line break with shift+enter. Nothing happens instead.

### When occurs:

According to my tests if I enable English-US layout and "Bangla(Probhat)" layout shift+enter (main enter key) does not add a line break. No matter which layout (US or Probhat) I have selected.

When the issue is there and if I try shift+NumpadEnter; I can type line break. (I forgot to mention it because I don't have numpad currently).

This issue is not only comes by adding "Bangla(Probhat)" but also with some other languages. (I'll test and edit here)

### When doesn't occur:

But strangely if I select the layout called "Bangla" the issue doesn't show up. More importantly, if I use the **m17n layouts** the problem doesn't show up. That's why I am using "Bangla(Probhat(m17n))" instead of "Bangla(Probhat)"

**Probable reason:** Probably some ibus issue. Of course I'm not sure.

### System Info:

OS: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
DE: Gnome 42.5
WS: Wayland
I did experience this issue on my older computers too, which were running linux mint 19, 20 etc.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. According to `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/bd` Jamil Ahmed didn't set anything on Shift+Return.  This question needs a clarification, the Enter key you mentioned is on the one upper row of Shift-R and not numeric keypad? Are you using a US keyboard or Bengali, which manufacturer and model? Upload photo, if you can.

Comment: This happens with my laptop and also with my external keyboard. I don't think it's model specific. Still I give you my model, it's Acer TMP 214 53. But again, this problem occurs with any device I have and it's not device specific. And when the issue is there the line break problem occurs with either US or BN layout selected

Comment: Shift+Enter is not registered as a unique character in Linux or Unix systems. It works a special code in some apps, e.g. MS Word, Opera browser and etc. `showkey -a` enter and shift+enter returns the same code `^M 13 0015 0x0d`. [Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/292868/how-to-customise-keyboard-mappings-with-wayland) some ideas to make it work is to configure an own keyboard map,  `key <RTRN> { [     Return,   Linefeed     ]   };` for example.

Comment: @SadaharuWakisaka but, this shift+enter works if I use only English keyboard. Or "Bengali" with English keyboard. Plus with some more layout selections. Which means it works in Linux at least in some cases. For instance, I'm currently using this as I said before. I'm using "Bengali(Probhat)(m17n))" with English and shift+enter works. Thank you for your suggestion I'll try that out too.

Comment: What is the difference to you between Enter/Return and Shift+Enter? Which application I can find it on Ubuntu?

Comment: @SadaharuWakisaka One adds new paragraph and the other adds a line break within the same paragraph. It works in any office software. But in case of other softwares like browsers or so, enter sends the posr while shift enter adds a new line. Same in telegram discord what'sapp

Comment: That is the difference between Enter and Return. I am not sure that it works or not. Please see the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo nano /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/bd`

Change the Line 52 (or something closer) into this

`key <RTRN> { [ Return KP_Enter] };`

Hope this works.